# How to specify output artifact from a cc_library in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I want to build "foo.c" as a library and then execute "readelf" on the generated .so but not the ".a", how can I write it in bazel?

The following BUILD.bazel file doesn't work:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.c"],
)

genrule(
    name = "readelf_foo",
    srcs = ["libfoo.so"],
    outs = ["readelf_foo.txt"],
    cmd = "readelf -a $(SRCS) > $@",
)
```

The error is "missing input file '//:libfoo.so'".

Changing the genrule's srcs attribute to ":foo" passes both the ".a" and ".so" file to readelf, which is not what I need.

Is there any way to specify which output of ":foo" to pass to the genrule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cc_library` produces several outputs, which are separated by output groups. If you want to get only .so outputs, you can use `filegroup` with `dynamic_library` output group.

So, this should work:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.c"],
)


filegroup(
    name='libfoo',
    srcs=[':foo'],
    output_group = 'dynamic_library'
)

genrule(
    name = "readelf_foo",
    srcs = [":libfoo"],
    outs = ["readelf_foo.txt"],
    cmd = "readelf -a $(SRCS) > $@",
)
```

Comment: Thanks, much better than my alternative solution to define a filter function and use it's target as the srcs of the genrule. Putting it here in case someone will find it useful.
```python
def _filter_so_impl(ctx):
    return DefaultInfo(files=depset([f for f in ctx.files.srcs if f.basename.endswith(".so")]))

filter_so = rule(
    implementation = _filter_so_impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True, mandatory=True),
    },
)
```