# How to list the output groups of a bazel rule?

Tags: bazel

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455700/6162120:

> `cc_library` produces several outputs, which are separated by output groups. If you want to get only .so outputs, you can use `filegroup` with `dynamic_library` output group.

Where can I find the list of all the output groups produced by `cc_library`? And more generally, how can I list all the output groups of a bazel rule?

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/9147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a replacement for documentation, but it's possible to get the output groups of targets using an [aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html):

`defs.bzl`:

```
def _output_group_query_aspect_impl(target, ctx):
  for og in target.output_groups:
    print("output group " + str(og) + ": " + str(getattr(target.output_groups, og)))
  return []

output_group_query_aspect = aspect(
    implementation = _output_group_query_aspect_impl,
)
```

Then on the command line:

```
bazel build --nobuild Foo --aspects=//:defs.bzl%output_group_query_aspect
```

(`--nobuild` runs just the analysis phase and avoids running the execution phase if you don't need it)

For a `java_binary` this returns e.g.:

```
DEBUG: defs.bzl:3:5: output group _hidden_top_level_INTERNAL_: depset([<generated file _middlemen/Foo-runfiles>])
DEBUG: defs.bzl:3:5: output group _source_jars: depset([<generated file Foo-src.jar>])
DEBUG: defs.bzl:3:5: output group compilation_outputs: depset([<generated file Foo.jar>])
```

Answer (score 4):

In the next Bazel release (after 3.7), or using Bazel@HEAD as of today, you can use `cquery --output=starlark` and the `providers()` function to do this:

```
$ bazel-dev cquery //:java-maven \ 
  --output=starlark \ 
  --starlark:expr="[p for p in providers(target)]"
["InstrumentedFilesInfo", "JavaGenJarsProvider", "JavaInfo", "JavaRuntimeClasspathProvider", "FileProvider", "FilesToRunProvider", "OutputGroupInfo"]
```

Comment: With 3.7.1 I get this: ERROR: Error doing post analysis query: invalid --starlark:expr: name 'providers' is not defined

Comment: 3.7.1 is just a patch release for 3.7, this is only available in 4.0 (currently available as release candidate) or later.